# Infinispan CacheEntryCreated not firing on Rebalance for primaryOnly=true?

Tags: cluster-computing, infinispan

we have recently started working with Infinispan running in embedded mode, we're currently using version `13.0.0`. What we want is a clustered storage that can guarantee that exactly one process is working with a given cache key at any given time. We want this guarantee to hold true even if new nodes join our cluster or old nodes leave.

One of the ways we figured this could be done would be to have a cache listener set with `@Listener(primaryOnly = true, observation = Listener.Observation.POST)`, that activates the code we want to be running. This technique works well for the first creation of the key in our cache. The problem is that once the node where the key was stored as its primary location leaves the cluster, the new primary owner node doesn't seem to get any event triggered informing that it has now "Taken over" this key from another node.

My question is if there's any way to know that a node has become primary owner of a key because the previous primary owner node has left the cluster?

To illustrate the problem I've done the following project: https://github.com/radiosphere/infinispan-test . You can clone it and checkout the tag `STACKOVERFLOW-1` . Once you have done this do the following:

1. Open three terminal windows and run `./start-server.sh 8080`, `./start-server.sh 8081` and `./start-server.sh 8082`.
2. Run `./set-key.sh 8080 a 1`
3. In one of the terminal windows you'll now see `Entry created`
4. Kill the process where you got the `Entry created` log.
5. Now I would have expected to see an event in another window, but I don't see any new event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CacheEntryCreatedEvent`s are only triggered when a key is inserted into the cache. Moving a key from a node to another does not trigger any events.

In any case, a node first receives an entry as a backup owner and only later becomes the primary owner of the key, so a node becoming the primary of a key is semantically very different from "create".

You can get what you want if you listen to `TopologyChangeEvent`s and iterate over all the entries for which the local node was not a primary owner before but is a primary owner now:

```java
@Listener(sync = false)
public class TopologyUpdateListener {
    @TopologyChanged
    public void onTopologyChange(TopologyChangedEvent<?, ?> e) throws InterruptedException {
       if (!e.isPre()) {
          Cache<?, ?> cache = e.getCache();
          Address localAddress = cache.getAdvancedCache().getRpcManager().getAddress();
          Set<Integer> oldPrimarySegments =
                e.getReadConsistentHashAtStart().getPrimarySegmentsForOwner(localAddress);
          Set<Integer> newPrimarySegments =
                e.getReadConsistentHashAtEnd().getPrimarySegmentsForOwner(localAddress);
          IntSet diff = IntSets.mutableCopyFrom(newPrimarySegments);
          diff.removeAll(oldPrimarySegments);
          cache.getAdvancedCache().withFlags(Flag.CACHE_MODE_LOCAL)
               .entrySet().stream()
               .filterKeySegments(diff)
               .forEach(entry -> { ... });
       }
    }
}
```

Sync listeners run on internal Infinispan threads, so they should never block. The `stream()` method does block, so I made the listener async for simplicity, but it's almost always a good idea to use your own executor for better control.

You can also replace `stream().filterSegments(diff)` with `localPublisher(diff)` and process the entries without blocking, but the `CacheCollection.localPublisher()` method is experimental and we are  planning to replace it with something else in 14.0.

Comment: Thanks you for a quick answer. I tried doing an implementation and in most cases it works. What I've found though is that when a new node joins the cluster, existing nodes get the topology change event as expected, but the new node does not seems to get any event upon its first join. This of course creates a problem with potential keys that migrate to the new joiner.

Example can be seen in the repo https://github.com/radiosphere/infinispan-test with the tag STACKOVERFLOW-2. Try doing `./start-server 8081`, add some sessions using `./create-session 8081 a..d` and then `./start-server 8082`.

Comment: Another question is I'm guessing one would have a potential race condition. Let's say that node A migrates a key to B. We don't have any guarantee that node B doesn't act quicker than A and starts its session before it's been closed on node B. This would just be a temporary overlap, but still a violation (if my assumption is correct).

Comment: Indeed, when a new node joins, you can only add a listener after the cache has joined the cluster, at which point it is very likely the primary owner of some of the keys already. So you have to invoke `onTopologyChange()` manually after you start the cache, only the "old primary segments" is the empty set and the "new primary segments" is from `cache.getAdvancedCache().getDistributionManager().getCacheTopology()`.

Comment: But you're right, there is a race condition -- in fact I just added `withFlags(CACHE_MODE_LOCAL)` in my example because during a test, when I started a new server, some keys moved during `stream.forEach(consumer)`, and Infinispan tried to execute the consumer on the new primary owner (which didn't work, because the consumer is not serializable).

Comment: I'm afraid you can't guarantee that the old primary stops before the new primary starts just with listeners, you need extra synchronization (e.g. when a node becomes primary, it sends a clustered executor task to the old primary and only starts a session after the old primary confirms that it stopped, or perhaps with clustered locks).